# How to define the order of executions using maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am working on the migration of a project from Ant to Maven. The final distribution I need to deliver is a zip containing an executable jar with all its depencencies. Here is part of my pom:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>ProjectDistribution</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>              
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>                            
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fullQualifiedNameToMainClass</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>                               
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>                      
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>dist</id>
                        <phase>assembly</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>                        
                </executions>                                       
            </plugin>
```

And here is the assembly file:

```
<assembly>
<id>dist</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats> 
<!-- 1st approach-->
<!--files>
    <file>
        <source>
            /target/ProjectDistribution.jar
        </source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </file>
</files-->
<fileSets>
            <!-- 2nd approach-->        
    <!--fileSet>
        <directory>/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <includes>      
            <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet-->
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/HelpFiles</directory>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

I run 1.- mvn compile, 2.- mvn package, and 3.- mvn assembly:single

**The problem I am dealing with is that**

It does generate the jar with all the dependencies and it does generate the zip  but it does not includ the jar in the zip. I pretty much need to figure out a way of making the assembly first generate the jar and wait until it is created (because its size is 5 MB) and then create the zip. Right now the 1st and 2nd approaches -from the assembly file- are commented out, however, I have used both and none of them seem to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Eric

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get this working you need to split the `<configuration>` and put it into the two plugin executions:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <finalName>ProjectDistribution</finalName>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>fullQualifiedNameToMainClass</mainClass>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>dist</id>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The first execution will create the jar file. The second execution will take that JAR file and 
 put it into the ZIP file together with the other files. With this configuration, you can just execute `mvn verify` or `mvn install` to create the assembly.

There are two other things to consider:

- You should use the *verify* phase to build your assembly because the jar-with-dependencies descriptor includes the project artifact itself. During the package phase the project artifact will not be ready for packaging
- The jar-with-dependencies descriptor has very limited capabilities to create a JAR file with all dependencies. You should use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) instead.

Comment: I am sorry but it is still not working. I made the changes you suggest and when I go with mvn verify or mvn install nothing is created. When I use mvn assembly:single it shows the following error message: "Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found." Could it be that since both configurations are inside of the executions maven does not know where to start? Thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: maven should work through the plugin executions in the order as they are defined (provided that the <phase> is the same in each execution).
did you make the configuration in <build><pluginManagement> or <build><plugins>?

Comment: I already tried the maven-shade-plugin but I don't seem to make it work. It does generate the jar but dependencies are not there. If you could please advice on how to create an executable jar with all its dependencies using the maven-shade-plugin and then I can go ahead and just use the assembly plugin to zip the jar. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Yes, they are inside of the following structure.. <build> ... <pluginManagement> ... <plugins> .. <plugin> .. I think the best thing to do right now is to use the maven-shade-plugin that you mention.. however I was not able to make it work before.. could you please advice on what I asked in the previous comment. Thank you so much!

Comment: i think, the `<pluginManagement>` is the problem. could you try to put the whole `<plugin>` part into `<build>...<plugins>...<plugin>`?
Regarding the maven-shade-plugin. You can easily stay with the jar-with-dependencies descriptor, if it works for you. I just wanted it to mention in case you once have a more complicated jar to build (e.g. a jar file that contains config files that have to be merged with configs from other JARs)

Comment: WOW!! It worked! The whole problem was being caused by the pluginManagement tag. Thank you very much Stefan!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the pre-defined `jar-with-dependencies` with a custom `zip` descriptor.  You would normally want one of them - not both.

It looks like you want a zip which contains your project artifact along with its dependencies.  For this you would not need to create a `jar-with-dependencies`.  If, however, you do want a single executable jar with all the dependencies in it, then it is not clear why you need to zip it again.

Comment: I need to zip it because the final distribution not only includes the executable jar but also license-related documents and manuals. My original idea was to use the predefined jar-with-dependencies - which works very well - and the resulting jar add it to the zip using the assembly file. Does it make sense? Do you know of a more efficient way to accomplish that?

Comment: What you say makes perfect sense. I'm sorry for not gettting it the first time, I'm new with maven. Could you please advice on how to generate an artifact (executable jar) with all its dependencies? Thank you so much!